# Add vertical braces to lists

Tags: math-mode, lists, braces

I want to add vertical braces to a list of group axioms, in order to determine which of the following axioms need to hold for monoids, groups and abelian groups. I'm not really sure how to achieve this. This is my code:

```
\subsection{Gruppen-Axiome}
Sei $G$ Menge mit einer inneren Verknüpfung $\circ:G\times G\to G$. In Zeichen: $(G,\circ)$\par \noindent
Es gelten folgende Axiome:
\begin{itemize}
    \item G0: $\forall a,b\in G: a\circ b \in G $ (Abgeschlossenheit) 
    \item G1: $\forall a,b,c\in G:(a\circ b)\circ c = a\circ
    (b\circ c)$ (Assoziativgesetz)
    \item G2: $\exists e\in G \quad \forall a \in G: a\circ e = e\circ a = a$ (neutrales Element)
    \item G3: $\forall a \in G \quad \exists a^{-1}\in G: a^{-1}\circ a=a\circ a^{-1}=e$ (inverses Element)
    \item G4: $\forall a,b \in G: a\circ b = b \circ a$ (Kommutativgesetz)
\end{itemize}
```

which outputs to:
[image: output of code]

but I actually want to achieve the following output (vertical braces):

[image: desired output]

How can I achieve this? I would be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution combining `bigdelim` and `listliketab`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\textbullet}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\subsection{Gruppen-Axiome}
Sei $G$ Menge mit einer inneren Verknüpfung $\circ:G\times G\to G$. In Zeichen: $(G,\circ)$\par \noindent
Es gelten folgende Axiome:

\storestyleof{itemize}
\begin{listliketab}
\begin{tabular}{Ll*{5}{r@{\,}}}
\tabitem & G0: $\forall a,b\in G: a\circ b \in G $ (Abgeschlossenheit) &\hspace*{-4em} \rdelim\}{2}{*}[xy] &\rdelim\}{3}{*}[\,Monoid] & \rdelim\}{4}{*}[Group] & \rdelim\}{5}{*}[ $\cdots$]\\
\tabitem & G1: $\forall a,b,c\in G:(a\circ b)\circ c = a\circ
(b\circ c) $ (Assoziativgesetz) \\
\tabitem & G2: $\exists e\in G \quad \forall a \in G: a\circ e = e\circ a = a$ (neutrales Element) \\
\tabitem & G3: $\forall a \in G \quad \exists a^{-1}\in G: a^{-1}\circ a=a\circ a^{-1}=e$ (inverses Element) \\
\tabitem & G4: $\forall a,b \in G: a\circ b = b \circ a$ (Kommutativgesetz) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's really cool!

Comment: Excellent combination. Very good.

Comment: Tante grazie for your kind appreciation, @Sebastiano.